# How to create GCP alerting policy with metric absence trigger for 1 day and longer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring, google-cloud-pubsub, metrics

I am trying to create the GCP alerting policy that should be triggered when messages haven't been pushed to the Pub/Sub topic for 1 day/1 week (quite rarely received data).
These time periods can be selected on the UI but seems like they are actually not supported because I am getting the following error when pressing 'Create Policy' button: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2UuI.png)
Could you advise me, please, if there are any workarounds to this? Probably configuring the metrics with such time periods isn't efficient and I should do it in some other way?

Thank you!